# Converting a VMware ESXi 4.0 Thin Provisioned VM to Citrix

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, citrix, conversion

I'm needing to convert a Centos 4.4 VM running on ESXi 4.0.0 to Citrix 6, however I'm not sure how to go about it as it's using thin provisioning.

Normally, I'd copy the *-flat.vmdk files over to another box and then run qemu-img to convert it to a raw .img file, then on the Citrix box import it onto the new VM via 'xe vdi-import', however will this work properly in this case? Would I need to create a drive for the provisioned size or the used size?

Would using the XenServer install media to do a P2V work?

Comment: Actually, I believe I have found the solution. I can simply inflate the vmdk and then copy it across.

Answer (score 1):

One method I am certain you could use is to download the free [VMware vCenter Converter Standalone](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_0).  Use that to pull a copy of the VM off the ESXi server, it has several different output formats.  It seems very likely that one of them will be compatible with XenServer.

Using the XenServer P2V should probably work as well, though I am not familiar with XenServer.

Comment: Hi Zoredache. I had a look at the tool, and found that it wouldn't have worked in this case. What I did in the end was clone the VM with thick provisioning and converted that :)